Same formulas give different answers
Practice Problem 6.66 from Fundamentals of Electric Circuits, Sadiku and Alexander
Q. The current i(t) through a 20 mH inductor is equal, in magnitude, to the voltage across it for all values of time. If i(0)=2 A, find i(t).
What the solution manual did:
Solved the differential equation $$\frac{dt}{L} = \frac{di}{i}$$ and obtained $$2 \cdot e^{50t} \ \text{A}$$.
What I did:
$$i(t) = \frac{1}{L} \int_{0}^{t} i(t) \, dt + i(0)$$
I got a quadratic equation in i(t). On solving it, I got
$$i(t) = 2\ \text{A}, \quad -1.96 \  \text{A}$$ without the exponential term.
Why doesn't the 2nd formula give the same answer as the 1st one, despite being equivalent?

Show the steps you used to solve your version.

Integrating leads to an i squared term, turning it into a quadratic equation. Solving it gives the two constant values, without the exponential term as the manual states.

Don't tell me. Show me. Keep in mind that the function you are integrating is also the function on the left. It's not independent.

I'd enjoy seeing your process for: $I=\frac1{L}\int I:\text{d}t =\frac1{L}\int \left[\frac1{L}\int I:\text{d}t\right]\text{d}t = \frac1{L^2}\int \left[\int I:\text{d}t\right]\text{d}t = \dots$

I see what went wrong. Thanks.

Your diff eq is wrong.

@FarhanS Good. Normally when I see something like $I_\text{L} = \frac1{L}\int V_\text{L}:\text{d}t$, I immediately do this:  $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\left{I_\text{L}\right} = \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\left{\frac1{L}\int V_\text{L}:\text{d}t\right}$ and get $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}I_\text{L} =\frac{V_\text{L}}{L}$. Which, of course, you already know is the standard equation describing inductors. The process looses a constant of integration. But I can always work that out, later.

@FarhanS  I could also just do: $\text{d}\left{I_\text{L}\right} = \text{d}\left{\frac1{L}\int V_\text{L}:\text{d}t\right}$ and find $\text{d}:I_\text{L} = \frac{V_\text{L}}{L}:\text{d}t$. Same thing. $\text{d}\left{\right}$ is just an operator, after all. And I can freely choose to then take the ratio of one infinitesimal to another (to get a finite answer) whenever I feel like it and using any independent variable I decide on, at the time. Doesn't have to be time. Could be anything I desire.

Assuming \$i(t)\$ and \$v(t)\$ as the current and voltage through that inductor:
$$i(t) = \frac{1}{L}\int_{0}^{t}v(\zeta)d\zeta+\mathrm{I_0} \qquad [1]$$
The problem states that \$i(t)=v(t)\$, for \$t \ge 0\$. Notice that, when writing that equality, there is actually a hidden unit converter factor:
$$i(t)=\frac{1 \space \mathrm{A}}{\mathrm{V}} \space v(t) \qquad [2]$$
Then, \$[1]\$ becomes:
$$i(t) = \frac{1}{L}\int_{0}^{t}i(\zeta)d\zeta+\mathrm{I_0} $$
Equations similar to the one above occur all the time; for example, when applying KVL to a mesh (in general, integro-differential equations).
Deriving it wrt time:
$$\frac{di}{dt}=\frac{1}{L}i \qquad [3]$$
Some notes here:

A differential equation, such as \$[3]\$, shows a relationship between a variable and
its derivatives.
The exponential function \$ e^{kx}\$ is one whose derivative is
proportional to the function itself.
We know that, in a general way, \$v(t)=L\frac{di}{dt}\$. But, through \$[2]\$, it's possible to conclude that the solutions for \$i(t)\$ and \$v(t)\$ will be exponential functions.

Using the method of separation of variables for solving \$[3]\$:
$$\frac{di}{i}=\frac{1}{L}dt$$
Integrating both sides:
$$\int_{\mathrm{I_0}}^{i}\frac{d\zeta)}{\zeta}= \frac{1}{L}\int_{0}^{t}d \xi$$
$$i(t)=\mathrm{I_0}e^{\frac{1}{L}t}$$
Or
$$
\boxed{
  i(t)=2e^{50t}
}
$$
The circuit below shows the equivalent circuit and a sketch for \$i(t) \ge 0\$:


NOTE
If the problem were changed so that \$i(t) = -v(t)\$, or better, \$i(t)=-\frac{1 \space \mathrm{A}}{\mathrm{V}} \space v(t)\$, for \$t \ge 0\$, a possible solution could be the free response of a series RL circuit, with \$R = 1 \space \mathrm{\Omega}\$ and initial current of \$-2 \mathrm{A}\$. This would be a more realistic circuit, but it is not what the problem in that book requires (I've checked the book's solutions manual and the resolution is consistent with what the OP reported at the beginning of the question).
For the new situation, the expressions for those current and voltage would be altered to:
$$
\begin{aligned}
  i(t)&=\mathrm{-2}e^{-50t} \\
  v(t)&= \mathrm{2}e^{-50t}
\end{aligned}
$$
The circuit below shows the equivalent circuit and a sketch for \$i(t) \ge 0\$:

